# Extra newline in git log with tformat

Tags: git, git-log

When I use `git log --pretty=oneline --shortstat`, I get a compact representation of my log:

```
% git log --pretty=oneline --shortstat
73c6eecd930c2f66d5c1e87fcca7ca9b0e356809 doing stuff with things
 3 files changed, 134 insertions(+)
65b457d2e0e94e628e1b30204075540524c8a1d2 doing things with stuff
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
...
375531279297af3c787855b0848b400f1c40b638 things with stuff doing
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
5501964b19815a07b64e1cd391e032147af33b8f with things doing stuff
 25 files changed, 6746 insertions(+)
```

But if I try to use the `tformat` equivalent of `oneline`, I get an extra newline before the stat:

```
% git log --pretty="%C(yellow)%H%Creset %s" --shortstat
73c6eecd930c2f66d5c1e87fcca7ca9b0e356809 doing stuff with things

 3 files changed, 134 insertions(+)
65b457d2e0e94e628e1b30204075540524c8a1d2 doing things with stuff

 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
...
375531279297af3c787855b0848b400f1c40b638 things with stuff doing

 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
5501964b19815a07b64e1cd391e032147af33b8f with things doing stuff

 25 files changed, 6746 insertions(+)
```

Without the `--shortstat` flag (or `--stat`) flag, the output of the two commands is identical, so it's something about adding those flags.

I can fix this with grep:

```
[alias]
  x-skip-empty-lines="!f(){ git $* --color=always | grep -vE '^(\\|{0,1}|\\e\\[[^m]*m)[[:space:]]*$' | less ;}; f"
  logpatch= !git x-skip-empty-lines log --pretty='%C(yellow)%H%Creset %s' --shortstat
```

But is there a way to avoid producing the newline in the first place?

(git 1.8.3 and 2.0.1)

Comment: What does `tformat equivalent of pretty` mean? Do you mean `tformat equivalent of pretty=oneline`?

Comment: Ok. :) (Didn't wanted to be too picky, I was just unsure and it seems like the question needs to be read correctly in order to answer it. also I'm not the git-super-hero) ... Back to the topic, it seems like this isn't the equivalent of `pretty=oneline`. (Because of different output) Where do you have the format expression from?

Comment: hek2mgl: It's the equivalent for this set of flags (I set `color=auto` in my `~/.gitconfig`). You'd need something different for `--abbrev-commit` or `--decorate`, but I wanted to give a small case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's nothing you can do about that.  In [log-tree.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/log-tree.c#L679), git has a special case for the oneline format, and always outputs two blank lines before the `shortstat` if it is not used.

(I've tried to compile git-log without the highlighted line - the original `--pretty=oneline` command then also outputs two blank lines)