# Extra newline in git log with tformat compared to oneline

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-log

Trying to reproduce `--oneline` using tformat produces an extra newline when combined with other options, for example:

```
$ git log --oneline --name-status 
c6104f2 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Remove the Slack chat badge, as nobody uses it anymore
M       README
f77d72b Fix SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault when scanning a now unexistent region.
M       ptrace.c
```

```
$ git log --pretty=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h%C(auto)%d %s" --name-status 
c6104f2 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Remove the Slack chat badge, as nobody uses it anymore

M       README
f77d72b Fix SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault when scanning a now unexistent region.

M       ptrace.c
```

the extra newlines do not appear without `--name-status`, but they come out for every extra option I tried.

This was already noted in [this 6 years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630021/extra-newline-in-git-log-with-tformat), and the answer back then was "nothing can be done".
I was hoping some new option was introduced in the meantime, or that this annoys enough people that someone knowledgeable can bring the concern to the git project.

Comment: if you need this for some text-base processing, you may consider to pipe this into sed or equivalent and trim the spurious return carriages. Are you looking for a git specific option?

Comment: I know I can patch stuff out after, but I'd like to combine this with, say, --graph, and so my newline stripper would become very complex. I am really looking for something like "%r - remove empty newlines after no matter what"